# YouTube video doesn't play

Tags: android

```
final String youtube = "<iframe class='youtube-player' type='text/html' width='200px' height='200px' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/7vcc68CY9Rw' frameborder='0'>";

        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);


        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                dialog.show();
                return true;
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                if(dialog.isShowing()) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });

        webview.loadData(youtube,"text/html", "utf-8");
```

I don't know  why youtube video doesn't play here, maybe  I missed write something? The webview load the data but when I press play button nothing happened there. what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just launch an intent to play the video and then let the user decide if they want their preferred browser or the YouTube app to play the video? When the user presses back they will return to your app. (note this may not work on emulators)

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxLG2wtE7TM")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just download source from here and check it.It works

http://code.google.com/p/html5webview/source/checkout

Answer (score 0):

put this in your webView client

```
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
  {
  // YouTube video link
  if (url.startsWith("vnd.youtube:"))
  {
   int n = url.indexOf("?");
   if (n > 0)
   {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(String.format("http://www.youtube.com/v/%s",    url.substring("vnd.youtube:".length(),n)));
 }
 return (true);
 }

 return (false);
}
```

it is better to start an intent with action view to view you tube videos..