# HTML5 Video in webview

Tags: android, html5-video, android-webview

I have a galaxy tab 10.1 with android 4.0.4

I try to make my video work in my webview but without success.

here is the code for the video.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls" >
      <source src="/public/files/vide1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

I try that with Internet explorer and it's working.
What I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: see the ans given by me at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682236/youtube-video-doesnt-play/9682386#9682386 just download project from the given links using svn checkout it works fine for me in which custome webview is used i have checked with **iframe** tag and it works let it check with video tag otherwise use iframe tag

Comment: Did you ever get this working?